# Generic Map to Class that extends a certain class

Tags: java, class, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to build a simple factory, where I get a class name of a class that extends `A` and return a new instance of it. For that I'm trying to build a map of class name to class object:

```
public abstract class A {

}

public class B extends A {

}

public class AFactory {
    private Map<String, Class<? extends A>> classesMap =
        new HashMap<String, Class<? extends A>>() {
            { 
                add("B", B.class);
            }
        };
}
```

But java won't except the call to add() ("`The method add(String, Class<B>) is undefined for the type new HashMap<String,Class<? extends A>>(){}`").

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because there is no method called `add` , it is `put` method in `HashMap` for adding key value pairs in the collection.

Comment: Thanks! I was too focused on the new concept (for me) of generics that I missed this silly detail...

Comment: @Elist, yes happens a lot of times with me too :D

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: @Elist No need to delete.Not a very bad question.Mark this answer as accepted